# I cannot keep the bean stateful when the spring bean is value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS

Tags: spring, proxy, prototype, javabeans

here is the spring bean:

```
@Repository
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class TestBean {
    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

and here is the very simple codes to access the bean:

```
    TestBean testBean = (TestBean) SpringContext.getBean("testBean");//#1
    testBean.setText("aaaaa"); //#2
    System.out.println(testBean.getText()); //#3
```

and the result is that testBean.getText() is null.

When i try to debug the codes, i found that the instance of testBean in #2 is not the same instance as that in #3. for example:

> #2: TestBean@988995e 
>    #3: TestBean@69bf7e71

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SpringContext.getBean("testBean")` returns the `Proxy` object for you. And any method invocation is delegates to the `DynamicAdvisedInterceptor`. Which, in turn, does `target = getTarget();` to generate `CglibMethodInvocation`. And the magic is hidden in that `getTarget()`, which is `SimpleBeanTargetSource` for the `prototype` beans and has a code:

```
public Object getTarget() throws Exception {
    return getBeanFactory().getBean(getTargetBeanName());
}
```

So, any method invocation on the `TestBean` asks `BeanFactory` for the new instance of that class. That's why your `setText("aaaaa")` isn't visible for `testBean.getText()`, because each method is for its `TestBean` object, not the same.

Such `prototype` objects can't be changed from the code manually. They are managed by `ApplicationContext` and only the last one can populate their internal state. From the code you can only read them.

And if your `TestBean` is populated with the same values you will get the same from the `testBean.getText()`, but all those call will be done for different objects.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent explanation! I found that it works if i change it to ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES. Could you tell me whether there is a way to  get the same cglib proxied bean after I get it from getBean(), instead of fetching a new instance every time i invoke the method of the fetched bean?

Comment: Don't do it as a Proxy at all! Since it is `prototype` you can't overcome that `object-per-invocation` stuff with proxying.